# Ajax call not working on appended items

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, ajax

i have a comment system which appends the newly posted comment to the rest. When the user hovers the comment a 'delete' button is shown.

When the user clicks the delete button, a confirm dialog is shown and if confirmed, it will complete an ajax call to remove the comment.

This works perfectly fine for comments that are already on the page, however the Ajax call doesnt seem to work on the appended items.

So an example comment looks like so:

```
    <div class='textcomment' id='".$commentID."'>
        <a class='$rightscommentcolor'>USERNAME:</a>&nbsp;
        THIS IS THE COMMENT TEXT
        <div class='commentActionButton'>
            <form action='process/deletecomment.php' method='post' class='delrepcomment'> 
                <input class='deletecommentsubmit' name='submit-delete' type='$buttontype' value='delete'>
            </form>
        </div>
    </div>
```

To show the button i use this:

```
    $(".commentsholder").on("mouseenter", ".textcomment", function(){
     var $this = $(this);       
     $(this).closest('.textcomment').find('.commentActionButton').show();
    });
```

And then the delete comment ajax:

```
    $(document).on('submit','.delrepcomment',function(){
    var $targetComment = $(this);

    if (confirm('Do you really want to delete this comment?')) {
    $.ajax({
    type: "POST",
    url: "process/deletecomment.php",
    data: $targetComment.serialize(),
    dataType: "json",
    success: function(response){
    if (response.commentDeleted === true) {
        $("#"+response.commentID).remove();
    }
    else {
        $('.delrepcomment').after('<div class="error">Something went wrong!</div>');
    }
    }
    });
    return false;
    } else {
       return false;
   }
    });
});
```

This all works okay, however when clicking the delete button on an appended comment the confirm dialog is shown but the comment is not deleted.

Which leads me to believe the ajax call isn't happening?

If i remove the ajax side of things and keep the form directly using the php page it works. Even on the appended comments, but it just doesnt work when the ajax is used.

The comment is appended like so:

```
if (response.commentSuccess === true) {
        $this.closest('.addcomment').prev().append("<div class='textcomment'><a class='"+response.userRights+"'>"+response.username+":</a>&nbsp;"+response.commentToPost+"<div class='commentActionButton'><form action='process/deletecomment.php' method='post' class='delrepcomment'><input class='deletecommentsubmit' name='submit-delete' type='submit' value='delete'></form></div></div>");
    }
```

Comment: Are you sure it really does go into the if (`response.commentDeleted === true` is true) and `response.commentID` has the correct value?

Comment: can you check the network tab of browser developer tools to see whether the ajax request is getting set, if so what are the parameters that are sent and what is the response from sever

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you append a new comment via AJAX, you aren't setting the `id` attribute of the `textcomment` div, so when you get back from the AJAX call, you are unable to locate it by id and remove it:

```
//DIV does not have id!
...append("<div class='textcomment'><a class='"+r...
```

Comment: The `id` is set in the response

Comment: But the div in the page does not have an id, so when he does `$('#'+response.commentID)`, this creates an empty jQuery object. Calling `.remove()` on it doesn nothing.

Comment: Besides, I'm not even sure he is sending the id of the comment to delete. The form he serializes to send via AJAX only has an input with somethink like a delete command, but not the id of the comment to delete. I don't know if he's getting it from another source, though I doubt it.

Comment: Nope, you are correct! Always something simple! Just need that second pair of eyes sometimes to check something over. Many thanks! I was already returning the ID so simply added the ID value into the div. For some reason i didnt add it when making the append value... Many thanks!